# Vue markup not rendering after migrating to Vite

Tags: vuejs2, vite

Made a migration from webpack to vite, made the same build model that was. But after the build, the div with the ID is empty, i.e. There vue2 does not render markup. Although all the view methods, such as beforeMount , work, it prints console logs. Nobody faced this?

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import { globSync } from 'glob';
import path from 'path';

const publicDir = 'static_mpa';
const filesForBuild = Object.fromEntries(
    globSync(`${publicDir}/**/{index.vue,*js}`).map(file => {
        return [
            path.relative(
                publicDir,
                file.slice(0, file.length - path.extname(file).length)
            ).replace('/index', ''),
            fileURLToPath(new URL(file, import.meta.url))
        ]
    })
);

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    publicDir: `/${publicDir}/`,
    base: '/',
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.css', '.js', '.vue', '.ts'],
        alias: {
            // '@': fileURLToPath(new URL(`./${publicDir}`, import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    build: {
        minify: 'terser',
        outDir: 'static/frontend/',
        assetsDir: './',
        rollupOptions: {
            input: filesForBuild,
            output: {
                format: 'es',
                entryFileNames: '[name].js',
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: what exact version of Vue?  is it only when building or does it work with local dev server?  can you include the component code with the div in question?

Comment: @yoduh, hi!
Vue version: tried 2.6.14 with vite-plugin-vue2, tried 2.7.0 with @vitejs/plugin-vue2
While I'm only setting up the build

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UdnOg2KnKLDvNeg0QrBmi8U-FgKuC_5YyN7HezWgkAQ/edit?hl=RU - vue example. 
Here it was inserted.